# Facebook API Post Message On Friends Wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I want to ask how to implement text view in Facebook API. I want to post message on friends wall and also how to get friends list and personal details from Facebook.

Comment: you should change your question to "Facebook API Post Message On Friends Wall" or something similar

Comment: Completely banned by Facebook, early 2013. Totally irrelevant now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665476/sending-a-private-message-to-your-friends-via-facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the IOS Facebook API. They created a quite detailed Introduction page.

Have a look here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

This image shows the whole process from authorization till publishing something on the news feed. (Also copied from the Facebook Developer tutorial)
[image: https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/ios-app-flow.png]

Describing the process to get the friend list:
[Facebook Api to check in users in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123931/facebook-api-to-check-in-users-in-an-ios-app/10126217#comment13062668_10126217)

Comment: Completely banned by Facebook, 2013.  Totally irrelevant now

Answer (score 0):

Due to many of errors and many of negative comment about Open Graph API in facebook ios 6.
facebook remove the " Post to friends wall via the API ". You can only  use the fbconnect of ios 5.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"100004925467891", @"to",
                               @"http://pri.com/pit.png", @"picture",
                               @"http://pr.com", @"link",
                               @"Data", @"caption",
                               @"data",@"description",
                               @"Birthday Reminder",@"name",nil];
[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But if u Post to own wall Open Graph API is still working.